# How to get all metrics data of a particular resource in GCP

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

Is there a way to get all the metric data for a specific resource?

I was trying with ListTimeSeries() method using the following request body

```
req := &monitoringpb.ListTimeSeriesRequest{
        Name:   "projects/" + projectID,
        Filter: `resource.type = "gce_instance" AND resource.labels.instance_id="123456789"`,
        Interval: &monitoringpb.TimeInterval{
            StartTime: &timestamp.Timestamp{Seconds: startTime},
            EndTime:   &timestamp.Timestamp{Seconds: endTime},
        },
        View: monitoringpb.ListTimeSeriesRequest_HEADERS,
    } 
iter := client.ListTimeSeries(ctx, req)
```

But we get an error stating:

> The provided filter matches more than one metric. TimeSeries data are limited to a single metric per request.

Tried client.ListTimeSeries(ctx, req) from cloud.google.com/go/monitoring/apiv3/v2/monitoringpb package

Is there any way to get all metric type data in golang rather than specifying a particular metric type in request body?

Answer (score 0):

The **ListTimeSeriesRequest** can only fetch metric data for a single metric type at a time. With the filter you applied, there can be many metric types. For example, your instance with *instance_id* as *"123456789"* can have multiple metric types like `bytes_used`, `cpu_utilization`, etc.
So, we must pass the metric type as a filter. Ex: `filter = 'metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/guest/disk/bytes_used"'`

To fetch all the metrics data for a particular resource, first we need to list out the metric types for that resource. Then we can iterate through the list of metric types and make the **ListTimeSeriesRequest**.

Here I've used **Python monitoring API** client to show sample:

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
from collections import defaultdict
import time
import pprint
    
client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_name = '''your project name'''
map = defaultdict(list)
    
for descriptor in client.list_metric_descriptors(name=project_name):
    if len(list(descriptor.monitored_resource_types)) != 0:
        resource_name = list(descriptor.monitored_resource_types).pop()
    else:
        continue
    metric_type = descriptor.type
    map[resource_name].append(metric_type)

start = time.time()
secs = int(start)
nanos = int((start - secs) * 10 ** 9)
end = seconds - 1200  # for 20mins interval from now
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
        {
            "end_time": {"seconds": secs, "nanos": nanos},
            "start_time": {"seconds": end, "nanos": nanos},
        }
    )
#  To get metric data for all resources
for resource, metric_list in map.items():
    for metric_type in metric_list:
        result = monitoring_client.list_time_series(
        name=project_name, filter=f'metric.type = "{metric_type}"', interval=interval,
        view=monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL, retry=None)
        for res in result:
            pprint.pprint(res)
#  To get metric data for any resource like "gce_instance"
for metric_type in map['gce_instance']:
    result = monitoring_client.list_time_series(
    name=project_name, filter=f'metric.type = "{metric_type}"', interval=interval,
    view=monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL, retry=None)
    for res in result:
        pprint.pprint(res)
```

Similarly, you can iterate through list of metric_types for any resource and make a **ListTimeSeriesRequest** to fetch metrics data.